# NAnt property::exists() with newly defined property?

Tags: nant

In NAnt 0.92, I define a property and immediately after checks it's existence. It doesn't exists... but it exists in a called target. Is this a bug or a feature?!? I search in the documentation but could not find a mention of it.

```nant
<target name="test">
  <property name="testprop" value="test value" />

  <echo message="property value = ${testprop}" />

  <if test="${property::exists(testprop)}">
     <echo message="property exists, as it should!" />
  </if>

  <if test="${not property::exists(testprop)}">
     <echo message="property doesn't exists... WTF?" />
  </if>

  <call target="test2" />
</target>

<target name="test2">
  <echo message="property value in sub-target = ${testprop}" />
</target>
```

Output:

test:

```
 [echo] property value = test value
 [echo] property doesn't exists... WTF?
```

test2:

```
 [echo] property value in sub-target = test value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the property needs to be quoted in your call to `property::exists`. So this is it:

```nant
<if test="${not property::exists('testprop')}">
  <echo message="property doesn't exists... WTF?" />
  <!-- don't swear -->
</if>
```

**Update:** What does happen in your example? The unquoted property `testprop` is replaced by it's value in your call to function `property::exists`. So you're in fact probing property `test value` (which BTW isn't a valid property name). Check this out:

```nant
<target name="test">
  <property name="test.value" value="foo" />
  <property name="testprop" value="test.value" />
  <echo message="property value = ${testprop}" />
  <if test="${property::exists(testprop)}">
    <echo message="property exists, as it should!" />
  </if>
  <if test="${not property::exists(testprop)}">
    <echo message="property doesn't exists... WTF?" />
  </if>
</target>
```

Output:

```
 [echo] property value = test.value
 [echo] property exists, as it should!
```

Comment: OH LOL!! I knew that already! I guess sometimes you just need someone to point out your stupid mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: what's the behavior of referencing an undefined property? `<echo message="This property does not exist  ${gibberishXYZ}" />` will that exit with error or be an empty string?

Comment: looks like undefined properties cannot be referenced `Property evaluation failed. Expression: This property does not exist${gibberishXYZ}"  Property '${gibberishXYZ' has not been set.`